# Should the reputation cap be relevant when earning "What's up Doc" hat?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

I created a documentation example, and earned an upvote on it:

[image: Reputation snapshot]

Since my reputation from voting has capped out for the day before the upvote arrived, there was no reputation change due to documentation upvote.

Description of "What's up Doc" hat says that you must earn reputation in docs, so I can see why I did not get the hat. However, this seems arbitrary, because earning a hat becomes dependent on the timing of documentation vote in relation to the timing of Q&A votes.

Do you think it would be a good idea to change the script to award the hat for reputation earned in the docs even if that reputation has been capped out?

Answer (score 1):

It's actually rather easy to get around that—[find a typo](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com/documentation+%22the+the%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-us) and fix it, and the +2 from approval [goes around the rep cap.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334551/6388243)

Comment: * Only works if you don't have instant editing privileges.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Although I can think of other ways to work around this issue (e.g. by temporarily deleting an answer that brought me over the cap, waiting for ten minutes for the doc rep to count, and then undeleting the answer) I think the timing shouldn't be relevant at all. In other words, earned reputation should count regardless of being capped out or not.